# Can erlang reuse process IDs? If so, how to be sure of correctness?

Tags: erlang

**(1)** After a process dies, is it possible that its `pid` is reassigned to another process created by `spawn()`?

**(2)** If so, how is any communication safe? For example, sending a reply to the `Pid` of the message's sender. If the sender has crashed, how can we know that this `Pid` doesn't belong now to another process?

**(3)** What guarantees are there on pid reuse? For example, is there a minimum interval before reusing a pid?

**(4)** What is usually done to prevent a bug due to pid reuse? Is it simply ignored?

Answer (score 11):

Quite a few questions...

1. Yes. PIDs can be reused.
2. Communication is "safe(ish)" because the chances of hitting a reused PID with any consistency is infinitesimally small. Hitting network and hardware error is *profoundly* more likely than this. *We design programs for robustness in the face of this* and that includes programming in a way that can accept erroneous messages and/or processes spontaneously dying (the cost of such a death is built into the restart cycle).
3. The guarantee on it is based, at least from what I have experienced with the main EVM implementation (not sure with HiPE, for example), on the fact that the integer assignment space is *quite large* and sending messages is *dramatically faster than integer wraparound* in most cases.
4. The key to avoiding weirdness based on PID reuse is to combine it with something else that is *also* a unique value within the typical span of use -- and that usually takes the shape of an [Erlang reference](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id62671).

Without getting exhaustive on the one hand and too pedantically handwavy on the other, let's consider a practical example: the OTP function [`gen_server:call/2,3`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#call-2).

When you use `gen_server:call/2,3` the gen_server module generates a combined message tag that looks like `{self(), make_ref()}` in addition to monitoring the process that is being messaged. The sending process is guaranteed that at least if the process it is calling dies before a reply is sent that a monitor exit message will be received instead of the response, and that the PID of the dying process will match the one it just called. The receiving process that is receiving the message will be receiving both the PID of the sender *and* an Erlang reference that is guaranteed to be locally unique (at least for a reasonably long time -- I believe the space of uniqueness is somewhere in the billions). When it sends its response the receiving process *must also know this reference* as well as be addressed by the PID originally used to send.

It is possible (though *extremely* unlikely) that the sending process could have died and a new process could have been respawned with the same PID, but it is very close to impossible for another process to be spawned with the same PID *and be blocking* on a `gen_server:call/2,3` message that happens to have an identical internal runtime reference as the old, dead call.

In addition to this near impossibility, let's consider a world where this one totally weird thing actually happened and all safeguards failed...

(on the order of `2^64 * 2^64 * chance_of_failure_on_this_tiny_scale()`)

The sending process would get a weird response message, and almost certainly fail an assertion match and die on the next line, and restart in a known state. The odds of that same problem happening twice is probably lower than a proton decaying within the next few minutes.

Is this "correctness"? No. There isn't such a thing as provable correctness in a massively concurrent system. That's like trying to "prove" a single equation that represents all of humanity. Most Erlang systems are chaotic by nature and so generally defy proofing as systems. What you *can* prove is that individual pure functions are correct, and that all the functions that a side-effecty process may call in its lifetime have definite termination conditions *to include crashing on wonky data*. That last part is how Erlang achieves such profound robustness as a system (well, good coding practices, adherence to functional principles and a strong culture of using Dialyzer helps a lot, too).

So... "correctness"... prove that on functions, as much as you can. It is a good thing and why we have tools like PropER and QuickCheck. As a general set of guidelines, try your best to write:

- **Functions that are pure** as often as possible. Have the side-effecty code be as isolated in code as possible from the pure code that does nothing but compute and return values.
- **Processes that are provably crashable**. Make every line have an `=` on it. This is why Erlang's `=` is assignment, assertion, and unification all in one.
- **Protocols that have provable states**. You can't make two identical processes call each other in a blocking way without a risk of a deadlock, for example. This is a fundamental limitation of concurrent systems. The CAP theorem is another. Design your systems against these constraints (which is oddly liberating) and *consciously choose your tradeoffs*.

Proofing at a scale larger than a function is a fool's errand unless you are in academia (that function may be calling a huge world of stuff beneath, so this isn't really much of a limitation). Proofing protocols for impossible or locked conditions is also possible, and if you have the time for this, go for it (otherwise do what the rest of us mortals do and stick to timeouts and rework code that has actually timed out on calls in its past -- this shouldn't be a regular occurrence).

All that said... Steve-O is almost certain to trip over a data cable in the data center and split a cluster many more times in the next two years than anyone is ever likely to see a PID wraparound cause an actual conflict in the next decade.

Comment: I wouldn't say that "it's "sage"".  Nothing in Erlang is.  You send a message and you basically don't have any guaranties, not even if there is someone on the other end of `!`.  If you need guaranties, if your domain require them,  you introduce them, by OTP, by linking to process, by `make_ref` and timeouts. You do it only when it's needed and only in manner that it's needed. And it makes your systems as flexible as domain allows it. That's how I see the Erlang way.

Comment: @mpm Indeed. I changed to express it as "safe(ish)" because that's really all we get. In addition, I am strongly against the ugly (and demonstrably unsafe) practice of deferring initialization by sending a *naked* message of the form `self() ! {do_something_with, Data}` in a gen_server's `init/1`. (I've actually experience a recycle bug with this case. Actually, it was never *really* clear to me until then that those cases are what staged init via `proc_lib`, `gen_*:enter_loop/3,4,5` and having process init be managed by an outside process are for.)